# Why do we need the first "as" in comparative structures like "The apple is *as* big as a watermelon."

Tags: comparative-constructions

Why do we need the first "**as**" in the sentence "**The apple is -as- big as a watermelon**."?

What's wrong in saying "The apple is big as a watermelon" in the same meaning of "The apple is **as** big as watermelon?

Is there an explanation for this structure of comparative sentences?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the first **as** is necessary to make the comparison

> **The apple**

is what?

> **The apple is as big**

as big as what?

Which could be left there if everyone knew what's being talked about, you could say this if you were pointing to a watermelon. Or you might say

> **The apple is as big as a watermelon**

alternatively you could say

> The apple is *(as)* big **like** a watermelon

Answer (score 1):

Comparatives are formed in English with as....as

The two words must be there.

Unless the comparison is implied because it's already in the conversation. But in written language, it is always needed.

However, bear in mind:

"The apple is big as a watermelon" is not grammatical. In fast speech, you might hear it, though and **it actually mean**s: as big as a watermelon.

If you compare things using as....as, that is called a simile.

- She is as silly as a mouse.
- He is as bad as an outright macho.
- They are as brutish as uncivilized beings.